# Server Side Ajax Rails 3

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a list of products and a column called 'sold'. When the user changes the status to false or true, I want my rails app, to update the html page index of the products, but only the "div" that contains the product's status, without reloading all the html page.
Is there a tutorial or a gem that will make my life easier? All the tutorial I found are for client-side AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

Server-initiated requests are not possible because, under HTTP, the "conversation" is always started by the client. If you really wanted to do this, you'd need to embed a server into your web page and have it open and listen on a port, which is problematic because there's no way to start a server from a web page and because many networks block incoming requests, with good reason.

Updating an already-displayed page is usually done by having the client poll the server over AJAX at regular intervals (like once every few seconds) to ask if anything has changed. One way to do it would be to have the client send the time of its last check, and to do a `Product.where("updated_at > ?", timestamp)` server-side and return that.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the product id to the row dynamically. add a class 'status' to the 'td' where u want to change the text.

```
%tr{:id => "product_#{product.id}"}
  %td Cell #Product
  %td.status Available
  %td #link_to controller method where product status is changed to 'Sold.'. Set ":remote => true" for request to be ajax.
```

create a file sell_product.js.haml (i m considering haml and sell_product as the controller method). in the js file search the table row with particular id and the $('.status').text() to "Available" and replace it with "Sold"